# MATLAB Convolution

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, convolution, infinite-impulse-response

I am designing an IIR notch filter using pole-zero placement method.  I am trying to convolve the two zero locations using

```
b1 = [1 exp(i*pi*filterFreq)];
b2 = [1 exp(-i*pi*filterFreq)];
b3 = conv(b1, b2)
```

which is producing the output of

```
b3 =

    1.0000    1.5917    1.0000
```

when instead I need it to be

```
b =

    1.0000   -1.5917    1.0000
```

I feel like this is just a misunderstanding of the math rather than MATLAB. Any advice appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A zero at $z = e^{j\theta_1}$ corresponds to the transfer function $H_1(z) = 1 - e^{j\theta_1}z^{-1}$. You have an implicit plus sign (rather than minus) in your vectors `b1` and `b2`.

Comment: what an oversight by myself.  Thank you! :)